# PowerShell date format mmddyy

Tags: date, powershell, formatting

I know I can set a date to a variable in PowerShell using

```
$a = Get-Date
```

It works great, but when looking through the documentation on formatting the date, there wasn't one for `MMDDYY`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$a` is effectively a [System.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx). You can do:

```
$a = Get-Date
Write-Host $a.ToString('MMddyy')
```

Full details on custom Date and Time Format Strings are in *[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)*.

Comment: how could I pass this variable to a batch script? Any idea?

Comment: Probably simpler would have been `$a = Get-Date -f MMddyy`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get creative with the `-UFormat` options.  To get exactly what you want run this:

`(Get-Date -UFormat %m)+(Get-Date -UFormat %d)+(Get-Date -UFormat %y)`

However I think this is much easier to read:

`Get-Date -UFormat %D`